# marker react native map can't drag

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

i' ve using react-native-map air bnb to render a google map in my native app.
The map and marker is showed up but the marker can't drag.
this is my script

```
<View style={Style.mapContainer}>
            <GeoLocation onSetInitalPos={this.onSetInitialPosition}
                         onSetLastPos={this.onSetLastPosition}/>
            <MapView style={Style.map} region={this.state.region} onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}>
                <MapView.Marker draggable={this.state.draggable}
                                coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}
                                title={this.state.marker.title}
                                description={this.state.marker.description}
                                onDrag={() => console.log('onDrag')}
                />
            </MapView>
            <AutoCompleteMap onSetNewPlace={this.setMarkerPosition}/>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md) of `react-native-maps` **draggable**:

> This is a non-value based prop. Adding this allows the marker to be draggable (re-positioned).

Instead of `draggable={this.state.draggable}`, you should be defining it like this

```
<MapView style={Style.map} region={this.state.region} onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}>
  <MapView.Marker
    draggable
    coordinate={this.state.marker.latlng}
    title={this.state.marker.title}
    description={this.state.marker.description}
    onDragEnd={this.onUserPinDragEnd.bind(this)} />
</MapView>
```

Here's a snippet of working draggable marker version of my project. Nothing fancy, just using Exponent Components to import MapView, instead of npm installing and linking.

```
   <Components.MapView
      ref={(map) => this.map = map}
      style={{width: Metrics.screenWidth, height: mapHeight, zIndex: 0}}
      region={{
        latitude: this.state.location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.location.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0100,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0100,
      }}
    >
      <Components.MapView.Marker
        key={'i29'}
        draggable
        onDragEnd={this.onUserPinDragEnd.bind(this)}
        title={'You are here'}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: this.state.userLocation.coords.latitude,
          longitude: this.state.userLocation.coords.longitude,
        }}
      />
   </Components.MapView>
```

And just to be sure, have you tried hold pressing the marker to drag it? It's kinda slow.

Comment: what's onUserPinDragEnd.bind??

Comment: @BraianMellor a custom function to be called when the drag ends. See the documentation

Comment: The documentation is not complete. that's why I ask you. I found  solution in a blog

Comment: how can i get the current lat & lng on the position where the marker stopped at ?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to define it as `draggable={this.state.draggable}`, or `draggable={true}` / `draggable={false}` in order to conditionally have the marker draggable.

Comment: what should i make when marker drag? onUserPinDragEnd can you tell me what contain ?

Comment: while using draggable property, it drags the marker but the map does not animates with it. Any help on this?